# Apply a Hover Effect to Headings Using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, fade, html-heading

I'm trying to achieve a fade on hover effect to the headings using CSS3 with no success. I'm not sure what I did wrong as I am pretty sure that I followed the W3 Schools tutorial.

Could you help me with fixing the code so I can get the fade on hover effect for my headings? The class that I'm trying to apply the hover effect is the .lesson-title, h1.

Meaning it would apply to those headings with names such as "Identify Your Business Opportunity" "Test Your Concept or Product", etc., etc.

They are also links so you could also apply the hover effect to them as another option.

Here is the code:

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
  
<style>

  .cm-lessons {
    background: #cecece;
    padding: 2em;
    max-width: 3000px;
    margin: auto;
}

    .cm-lessons h1{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #00455e;
    }
    
.cm-lessons ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
  
.cm-lesson-marker span, ol, ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
   color: #00455e;
    vertical-align: baseline;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #00455e;
}
  
 .last-lesson{
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 100%;
   color: #00455e;
    vertical-align: baseline;
   border: none;
  }
  
  .cm-lesson-marker h1{
 font-size: 3em; 
  }
  
  #more-lessons{
   max-height: 0;   
    overflow: hidden;
   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  .lesson-title h1, h2, h3, u, ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
   color: #00455e;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 170ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

  
  .lesson-title h1:hover{
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 170ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }  
  
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}


.collapsible {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00455e;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}


  </style>
  </head>
  
  <div>
    <ul class="cm-lessons">
    <h1>
    For First-Time Business Owners
    </h1>
      <h3>
        Lesson plans: 8
      </h3>
       <h2 class="lesson-title">
         One hour webinar over a duration of 8 weeks.
      </h2>
    <li class="cm-lesson">
      <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
        <h1>01</h1>
      </span>
      <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-01">
        <h1 class="lesson-title">Identify Your Business Opportunity</h1>
      </a>
      <p>Choosing what kind of business to start with can be a challenging task when confronted with many ideas and opportunities. It’s important to determine where your passions lie and to understand what it takes to start the business. You have to consider your skills and resources. The industry you are entering may be dying or a fast-growing and emerging business.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
          <h1>02</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-02">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Test Your Concept or Product</h1>
        </a>
        <p>Concept testing is the process of evaluating likely customer response to a product idea prior to its introduction into the market. Seen through a jobs-to-be-done lens, the goal of concept testing is to validate that a product concept is better than the competing solutions at helping customers to get a job done.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker"><h1>03</h1></span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-03">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Name Your Business</h1>
        </a>
        <p>Naming your business is important. The right business name will help you distinguish you from a sea of bland competitors, hence provide your customers with a reason to remember and use your company.  </p>
      </li>
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
          <h1>04</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-04">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Build a Business Plan</h1>
        </a>
        <p>For any start-ups, a business plan is an important tool and it also allows you to gain a better understanding of your industry structure, competitive landscape and the capital requirements of starting the small business. The plan lays out a vision of growth and the steps needed to get there. 
        </p>
      </li>
      <button class="collapsible">More lessons</button>
      <div id="more-lessons">
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
          <h1>05</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-05">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Find Start-Up Money</h1>
        </a>
        <p>To start a business, you must invest in the business. The journey of finding start-up funds will be different for each individual. Some businesses require small amount or large amount of money to start.  Finding the money you need may come from a source you would have never thought of. 
</p>
      </li>
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker"><h1>06</h1></span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-06">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Choose a Business Structure</h1>
        </a>
        <p>Deciding on the structure of your business is not a decision to be taken lightly. Whether you have the LLC, a sole proprietorship or form a corporation; your choice will have an impact on your business liability and taxes. </p>
      </li>
      <li class="cm-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
          <h1>07</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-07">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Get Your Business Licenses and Permits</h1>
        </a>
        <p>Depending on your chosen business structure, may need to register your business with the state authorities. Setting up your small business may require an employer identification number (EIN) which is also used by state taxing authorities to identify businesses. Additional paperwork can entail sales tax licenses and zoning permits. </p>
      </li>
        <li class="cm-lesson last-lesson">
        <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
          <h1>08</h1>
        </span>
        <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-08">
          <h1 class="lesson-title">Get Business Insurance</h1>
        </a>
        <p>As a new small business owner, you have the responsibility to manage the risks associated with your business. Don't put your new startup at risk without getting the proper small business insurance to protect your company in the event of a disaster or litigation.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
  
  </html>
```

It will need to stay in HTML format as I will be copying/pasting this into a drag-and-drop website editor. Sorry for the messy code.

Thanks! If you need any more details, reply to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've gotten your tag wrong:

```
.lesson-title h1:hover{
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 170ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
```

should be

```
h1.lesson-title:hover{
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
    transition-duration: 170ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
```

The original selector means on hover for h1 which are a child of .lesson-title.

Whereas what you wanted to say was on hover for h1 which have the class .lesson-title.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree with @Okkio, you got the style parenting wrong it should be **h1.lesson-title:hover** or **.lesson-title:hover** instead of **.lesson-title h1:hover**

Answer (score 0):

Super simple: remove your `class="lesson-title"` from the `<h1>` tag (and `.lesson-title h1:hover` CSS) altogether. Then it works (see below).

```css
h1:hover{
        opacity: 0.2;
        transition: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
        transition: 170ms ease-in-out;
        transition-duration: 170ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        transition-delay: 0s;
      }
```

```html
          <li class="cm-lesson">
            <span class="cm-lesson-marker">
              <h1>02</h1>
            </span>
            <a href="http://www.yantern.com/webinar001-02">
              <h1>Test Your Concept or Product</h1>
            </a>
            <p>Concept testing is the process of evaluating likely customer response to a product idea prior to its introduction into the market. Seen through a jobs-to-be-done lens, the goal of concept testing is to validate that a product concept is better than the competing solutions at helping customers to get a job done.</p>
          </li>
```